# RPi3 power consumption based on CLI or Desktop GUI. Which consumes more power? CLI vs Desktop GUI

Tags: electronics, battery

I am planning to do a project where RPi3 will b run by a powerbank. But I am bit confused with power consumption and in my project I am not running any heavy load expect camera interface. In my case RPi3 will run a bash script on startup and enable camera interface. But I like to do it on CLI interface while startup. So using GUI generally consumes more power than CLI?

Answer (score 1):

according to https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=223399

> Well, an HDMI connection will use a tiny bit more power. As for the OS
>   itself, running the GUI requires more software, and that would put
>   more load on the SoC, but I doubt it would have a large impact on
>   total power consumption. And as klricks said above, the Desktop
>   version of Raspbian can be configured to boot to the CLI (not load the
>   GUI).